# Check if variable exists

Tags: python

So a common issue and I've tried several solutions but nothing is working so far.

Here is my code excerpt. I need to get the last line t2.kill() to run.
This example gives me a 
UnboundLocalError: local variable 't2' referenced before assignment

```
if id2 is not None:
    if id2 == 0;
        op('person2').op('hold').run()
        op('ring2').op('constant1').par.value0=0
        t2 = run(func, "ring2",delayMilliSeconds=d)             
    elif id2 > 0:           
        if t2 is not None:
            t2.kill()
```

If instead I try the following to check for the existence of t2

```
 if 't2' in locals():
```

I get no error but t2 doesn't exist in locals so the following line isn't run!

What to do?

Comment: Is the first code snippet inside a loop? If not why would t2 be defined before the if statement?

Comment: If this _is_ in a loop, just define `t2 = None` in the loop scope.

Comment: @hmm: even if it's not in a loop, `t2` must be defined somewhere

Comment: ok so if I understand set default value to None. It would get redefined in the 't2=run...' line so everything would still work?

Comment: Yes, that's why it's called a variable: because it can change the value

Comment: In the given snippet, i could see t2 is only initialised if `id2==0`, so if value of id2 is greater than 0 directly is will execute `t2.kill()` and will throw refference before initialised error

Answer (score 0):

To check a variable exist or not, not a good idea. Maybe you can try this

```
t2 = None
if id2 is not None:
    if id2 == 0:
        op('person2').op('hold').run()
        op('ring2').op('constant1').par.value0=0
        t2 = run(func, "ring2",delayMilliSeconds=d)
    elif id2 > 0:
        if t2 is not None:
            t2.kill()
```

or

```
if id2 is not None:
    if id2 == 0:
        op('person2').op('hold').run()
        op('ring2').op('constant1').par.value0=0
        t2 = run(func, "ring2",delayMilliSeconds=d)
    elif id2 > 0:
        try:
            t2.kill()
        except:
            pass
```

Answer (score 0):

```
t2 = None
if id2 is not None:
if id2 == 0;
    op('person2').op('hold').run()
    op('ring2').op('constant1').par.value0=0
    t2 = run(func, "ring2",delayMilliSeconds=d)             
elif id2 > 0:           
    if t2 is not None:
        t2.kill()
```

Jus assign a value to t2, as it will change in the loop anyways, it is not of great significance to assign it at the start.